# How to handle Item clicks for a recycler view using RxJava

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, rx-android

I was interested to find out what is the best way to respond to a item click of a recycler view.

Normally I would add a onclick() listener to the ViewHolder and pass back results to the activity/fragment through a interface.

I thought about adding a Observable in the onBindViewHolder but i do not want to create a new Observable for every item binding.

Comment: You can use a PublishSubject. Then you create it only once and you just emit data on it, while having subscribed only once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) and then create a subject inside of your adapter, then redirect all the events to that subject and just create a getter of the subject to act as an observable and finally just subscribe you on that observable.

```
private PublishSubject<View> mViewClickSubject = PublishSubject.create();

public Observable<View> getViewClickedObservable() {
    return mViewClickSubject.asObservable();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup pParent, int pViewType) {
    Context context = pParent.getContext();
    View view = (View) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, pParent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    RxView.clicks(view)
            .takeUntil(RxView.detaches(pParent))
            .map(aVoid -> view)
            .subscribe(mViewClickSubject);

    return viewHolder;
}
```

An usage example could be:

```
mMyAdapter.getViewClickedObservable()
        .subscribe(view -> /* do the action. */);
```

Comment: Where do you unsubscribe?

Comment: Yo can handle that where you do the subscription. Probably using a Composi teSubscription if you have more than one subscription there.

Comment: if u need only observable(in general way!)  - u need to call mViewClickSubject.asObservable().

otherwise every subscriber can call onErro()(for example, which is not ok!

Comment: @epool What is the use of `.takeUntil(RxView.detaches(pParent))`? Any way once view gets recycled there will be no click emits, so do we have to stop the click stream once the view get detached from the parent?

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan most likely is in order to unsubscribe when the view is detached. This happens when the item is scrolled out of screen.

Comment: @Odys That's true. But I have an issue with using this approach in fragments. And I couldn't get this `takeUntil()` work in that case, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433115/recyclerview-item-click-using-rxjava2-rxbinding-not-working-after-fragment-rep/44840296). Is it enough to call `onCompleted` on `onDetachedFromRecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Move the business logic out of the activities to domain classes/services

Optional: Use https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice to easily wire up your services with each other.

Step 2: `@Inject` (or just set) your service into your adapter

Step 3: Grab `https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding` and use the super powers in your adapter:

```
RxView.clicks(button).subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Void aVoid) {
        myCoolService.doStuff();
    }
});
```

Step 4: Get a runtime crash and learn how to deal with subscriptions

Step 5: PROFIT :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do with your initial aproach of an observable per element on click, but in order to avoid create a new observable every time you can just cache the items emitted the first time using cache.

```
      /**
 * Here we can prove how the first time the items are delayed 100 ms per item emitted but second time becuase it´s cached we dont have any delay since 
 * the item emitted are cached
 */
@Test
public void cacheObservable() {
    Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.from(numbers)
                                               .doOnNext(number -> {
                                                   try {
                                                       Thread.sleep(100);
                                                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                                   }
                                               })
                                               .cache();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("First time took:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("Second time took:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was much like @epool 's except use EventBus model.

First, create a RxBus: 
RxBus.java

```
public class RxBus {
    private final Subject<Object, Object> _bus = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());
    public void send(Object o) { _bus.onNext(o); }
    public Observable<Object> toObserverable() { return _bus; }
    public boolean hasObservers() { return _bus.hasObservers(); }
}
```

Then, you have two way to use RxBus. Create your custom Application class with RxBus reference or create RxBus in Activity/Fragment then pass it to adapter. I'm use the first.

MyApp.java

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp _instance;
    private RxBus _bus;
    public static MyApp get() {  return _instance; }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        _instance = this;
        _bus = new RxBus();
    }

    public RxBus bus() { return _bus; }
}
```

then use

```
MyApp.get().bus()
```

to get RxBus instance.

The usage of RxBus in Adpater was like this:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends ... {
    private RxBus _bus;

    public MykRecyclerAdapter (...) {
        ....
        _bus = MyApp.get().bus();
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (...) {
        _sub = RxView.longClicks(itemView)  // You can use setOnLongClickListener as the same
              .subscribe(aVoid -> {
                        if (_bus.hasObservers()) { _bus.send(new SomeEvent(...)); }
                    });      
    }
}
```

You can send any class with _bus.send(), which We will recieve in the Activity:

```
RxBus bus = MyApp.get().bus();  // get the same RxBus instance
_sub = bus.toObserverable()
            .subscribe(e -> doSomething((SomeEvent) e));
```

About unsubscribe.

In MyRecyclerAdapter call _sub.unsubscribe() in clearup() methods and call _sub.unsubscribe() in Activity's onDestory().

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (_adapter != null) {
        _adapter.cleanup();
    }
    if (_sub != null) {
         _sub.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We generally need the Pojo/Model class from list on clicked index. I do it in following way:

1) Create a `BaseRecyclerViewAdapter`

```
abstract class BaseRecyclerViewAdapter<T> : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private val clickListenerPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create<T>()

    fun observeClickListener(): Observable<T> {
        return clickListenerPublishSubject
    }

    fun performClick(t: T?) {
        t ?: return
        clickListenerPublishSubject.onNext(t)
    }
}
```

2) In any adapter (For example `MyAdapter`)

```
class MyAdapter(private val events: List<Event>, context: Context) : BaseRecyclerViewAdapter<Event>() {
    //... Other methods of RecyclerView
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        if (holder is EventViewHolder) {
            holder.eventBinding?.eventVm = EventViewModel(events[position])

            holder.eventBinding?.root?.setOnClickListener({ _ ->
                // This notifies the subscribers
                performClick(events[position])
            })
        }
    }
}
```

3) Inside the `Activity` or `Fragment` where click listener is needed

```
myAdapter?.observeClickListener()
                ?.subscribe({ eventClicked ->
                    // do something with clicked item

                })
```